# SQL Availability Group Network

Tags: sql-server

On a SQL Availability Group what IP/network carries the workload of moving changes to the secondary replica and how do you find this network?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your question:

- to check where network packet will go look at results of `ROUTE PRINT` (Hit [Windows]+[R], type `CMD`, hit [Enter]). Read [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122.aspx) on Technet.
- with `TRACERT x.x.x.x` (where x.x.x.x is your secondary replica servers IP address) you will see a [route that's packet travels](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/162326).